# Proper way to use the comma when having a similar items in a list with one exception

Tags: commas

What I am trying to say..

The thermal conductivity of a material is dependent on its crystal structure, phase , microstructure and doping level (for semiconductors).

What I wrote..

The thermal conductivity of a material is dependent on its crystal structure, phase and microstructure – and doping level for semiconductors.

Is this the correct usage of em-dash or can you suggest a better way.

Thanks

Comment: How about "microstructure, and --- for semiconductors ---the doping level" (no real dashes on my phone)

Comment: How to use commas in this sort of sentence is an age-old question.  (I remember it being discussed in 3rd grade, and that was a loooong time ago.)  I think the rule-makers change their minds every 20 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that semiconductors are a subset of the class "materials" and that the semiconductor subset has an additional factor affecting thermal conductivity. Mere punctuation will not clearly communicate all of that information. To make it easier on your reader, be explicit and write something like, "and for semiconductors, doping level is an additional factor."

The main purpose of punctuation is to signal groupings of ideas, not to express the ideas themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> The thermal conductivity of a material is dependent on its crystal structure, phase, microstructure, and (for semiconductors) doping level .

Answer (score 0):

This is snappier:

> The thermal conductivity of a material is dependent on its crystal structure, phase, and microstructure, and for semiconductors, also doping level.